# How can I set the colors per value when coloring plots by a DataFrame column?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colors, seaborn

In matplotlib (in particular, pandas), how can I map specific colors to values of a column that I use for differentiating colors?

Let's say I have a column ...

```
>> df["country"]
DE
EN
US
DE
```

... and now I'd like to plot values from the DataFrame where each country is colored differently. How can I determine which country gets which color? With a colormap? I wasn't able to find the proper documentation, unfortunately.

I would like to apply a dict like this:

```
# pseudo-code
colormapping = {"DE": "blue", ...}
df.plot(colorby="country", colormapping)
```

Edit:

Here's a sample DataFrame.

```
    outlook   play  temperature country
0     sunny   True           25      DE
1     sunny   True           25      EN
2  overcast   True           19      DE
3      rain  False           21      US
4  overcast  False           33      IT
5      rain  False           27      EN
6      rain  False           22      FR
7  overcast   True           26      FR
8     sunny   True           13      FR
9     sunny   True           16      CH
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample `dataframe` for the purpose?

Comment: @NickilMaveli: Sure, please see my edit!

Comment: What kind of a plot are you expecting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do so by specifying the dictionary mapping of hue levels to corresponding `matplotlib` colors in the [`palette`](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/color_palettes.html) argument of a [`categorical plot`](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/categorical.html) using `seaborn` as shown:

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
sns.swarmplot(x="outlook", y="temperature", hue="country", data=df, size=8,
              palette={'DE':'b', 'EN':'g', 'US':'r','IT':'c', 'FR':'y', 'CH':'k'})
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you :-)

Comment: A bit unlucky that seaborn handles this more complicated than matplotlib itself, where you can pass the column/array with your color codes in `c=` directly as argument...